# Code not working as intended with some weird errors in a class

Tags: php

Basically my problem is as follows. I put the following code in the browser
 `?phase=1&step=0&fot=false` and I get a black page.

The Apache server errors are as follow

`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: true in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Proj11\1.php on line 9`

This one is expected as is the line `} elseif ($_GET['true']) { $fOT = 'true'; }` in the beginning.

`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: true in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Proj11\1.php on line 138`

This one is the same line as before but inside the __construct of phase2 class

`PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: fOT in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Proj11\1.php on line 17`

is the line `$phase->stepFunction($fOT);` at the top of the script.... it was defined so dunno why the error....

I don't know why is not doing anything, I appreciate the help thx

Thank you guys!

```
            if (empty ($_GET['fot']) ) { 
                    $fOT = 'false'; 
                    } elseif ($_GET['true']) { $fOT = 'true'; }

            $phase = $_GET['phase'];        
            if(empty ($phase)){
                $phase = new phase1();
                $phase->start();
                } elseif ($phase = 1) {
                    $phase = new phase2();
                $phase->stepFunction($fOT, $_GET['step']);
                    }
                 class phase 1 { ... }

                    class phase2 {
        function __construct () {

        $dbFile = 'dbconfig.php';
        $this->dbFile = $dbFile;
        include_once ("$this->dbFile"); 


        $step = $_GET["step"];

        $username = $DB_USER;
        $password = $DB_PASS;
        $server = $DB_SERVER;
        $dbName = $DB_NAME;

        $this->step = $step;
        $this->dbFile = $dbFile;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->dbName = $dbName;

        $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=' .$server.';dbname='.$this->dbName,$this->username,$this->password);

        $this->db = $db;

        if (empty ($_GET['fot']) ) { 
        $fOT = 'false'; 
        } elseif ($_GET['true']) { $fOT = 'true'; }

    $this->IDB = $this->handleDatabase( 1 );
    $this->IDB2 = $this->handleDatabase( 2);
    $this->IDB3 = $this->handleDatabase( 3);
        }



public function handleDatabase ($num = 1){
// Prepare SQL Statements
    $IDB1 = $this->db->prepare( 
         "CREATE TABLE pages (
          id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
         subject_id int(11) NOT NULL,
          menu_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
          position int(3) NOT NULL,
          visible tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
          content text NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    )ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

    $IDB2 = $this->db->prepare("
        CREATE TABLE subjects (
          id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
          menu_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
          position int(3) NOT NULL,
          visible tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    )ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

    $IDB3 = $this->db->prepare("
        CREATE TABLE users (
          id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
          username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          hashed_password varchar(40) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    )ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

    $name = "IDB".$num;
return isset( $$name)?$$name:false;
}
//Set Option to True or False

function createTablePages ($fOT){

    $r1 = $this->db->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'page\'');
    if (count($r1->fetchAll()) > 0 && $fOT == 'false') {
        echo "The table PAGE exists";

    } elseif ($fOT == 'true') {
        $this->IDB->execute();
        echo "enteres";
                $this->stepFunction (1,false);
    }
}
function createTableSubjects ($fOT){

    $r2 = $this->db->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'subjects\'');
    if (count($r2->fetchAll()) > 0  && $fOT == 'false') {
        echo "The table SUBJECTS exists ";

    } elseif ($fOT == 'true') {

        $this->IDB2->execute();
        $this->stepFunction (2,false);

    }
}

function createTableUsers ($fOT){

    $r3 = $this->db->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'users\'');   
    if (count($r3->fetchAll()) > 0  && $fOT == 'false') {
        echo "The table USERS exists";
    } elseif ($fOT == 'true') {
        $this->IDB3->execute();
        echo "Would you like to populate all the tables?";
    }   
}


public function stepFunction ($fOT,$step){

switch ($step) {
    case 0: 
            $this->createTablePages ($fOT);
            break;
    case 1: 
            $this->createTableSubjects($fOT);
            break;
    case 2: $this->createTableUsers ($fOT);
            break;
    }


}

    }
```

Comment: I don't see any syntax errors in your code. I would try commenting out your code until you can find what is actually going on. Also, you should try to stay consistent with the visual structure of the code, like always make a new line after a opening brace, always indent consistently, might make it easier to spot a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use variables defined within a method on the global scope.

Change this and it will solve some errors

```
    $this->IDB = $this->handleDatabase()->$IDB;
    $this->IDB2 = $this->handleDatabase()->$IDB2;
    $this->IDB3 = $this->handleDatabase()->$IDB3;
```

to

```
    $this->IDB = $this->handleDatabase( 1 );
    $this->IDB2 = $this->handleDatabase( 2);
    $this->IDB3 = $this->handleDatabase( 3);
```

and function handledatabase to

```
public function handleDatabase ( $num = 1){
// Prepare SQL Statements
$IDB1 = $this->db->prepare( 
     "CREATE TABLE pages (
      id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
     subject_id int(11) NOT NULL,
      menu_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      position int(3) NOT NULL,
      visible tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
      content text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

$IDB2 = $this->db->prepare("
    CREATE TABLE subjects (
      id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      menu_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      position int(3) NOT NULL,
      visible tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

$IDB3 = $this->db->prepare("
    CREATE TABLE users (
      id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      hashed_password varchar(40) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

$name = "IDB".$num;
return isset( $$name)?$$name:false;
}
```

Or just set $this->IDB directly in the method:

```
public function handleDatabase ( ){
// Prepare SQL Statements
$this->IDB  = $this->db->prepare( [...]
```

There are also a few other issues

```
 $this->IDB3->execute;
```

Wont do anything, change to:

```
 $this->IDB3->execute();
```

Comment: thx I did that and it solve those errors. but i am still getting the other ones and the page remains blank :S

Comment: What other ones? And I dont see any output in the code you posted, except some errors. PS, you also did not change the method as I suggested completely. Look closely.

Comment: I made the changes now, Thank you. There should be some output coming out of the functions that enter in the `switch` statement. `createTablePages` `createTableSubjects` and `createTableUsers` have output to check that they are working properly

Comment: Look a little bit closer still, you are almost there ;-). Alright, good luck!